# Is it possible to use ml-gradle on MarkLogic 9 without the Admin role?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, ml-gradle

I am working with ml-gradle on MarkLogic 9 but would like to configure the MarkLogic account running ml-gradle with the principle of least-privilege. Is it possible to configure the ml-gradle user in MarkLogic to have more granular permissions, or am I stuck using the admin role?
The deployment will be fairly standard, creating documents, modules, indexes, query options etc.

Thanks,
--Dan

Answer (score 2):

To create app servers, databases, etc., you'll need the `manage-admin` privilege. To create documents and otherwise modify database content, you'll generally need rest-writer. To read documents or do searches, you'll need rest-reader. On top of that, you may need permissions for specific docs.

see the [Basic Security Requirements](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/intro#id_59939) section of the REST Application Developer's Guide for more information.

Comment: Thanks, what about defining an index? would that require rest-writer, or something else?

Comment: In addition, please note that MLGradle has many user configurations for the various ways that it connects (configuration, etc).  Please get used to the settings in this example file. https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/blob/master/examples/sample-project/gradle.properties  I set the 3-4 users myself to ensure that I am not getting a user still connecting as admin after I have thought that it has been connecting as my specific user.

Comment: @dan it looks from http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties that you would need the manage-user role or the http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/manage privilege.

Comment: After a bit of delay I finally got back to working on this. I am still having trouble with minimal permissions. I can successfully run the ml-gradle project to load new modules when i have the 'admin' role, but when i limit it to 

Roles:
manage-user
qconsole-user
rest-reader
rest-writer
Execute Privileges:
any-uri
any-collection
create-trigger
protect-collection

It will not upload the new modules. Is there any permission/role that i might be missing?
Thanks,
--Dan

Comment: not sure what you're missing, but check the error log (note that in ML9, there are separate logs for each app server). There should be an error there that tells you what privilege you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

Creating users and roles requires the "security" role too. The Manage docs - http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management - do a good job of explaining which privileges are needed for each resource.

In addition, the ml-gradle Property Reference - https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Property-reference - describes the different connections that ml-gradle makes and for what purpose, though there's a ticket open to provide more comprehensive documentation of the different users and roles and connections.